# Excel VBA Buttons with different SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

Some of the user wanted to filter different statuses, so I create a button with label to tell them how many where in that status. By default on my listview is shows all the transactions. Now for example, for new volume button, when the user clicks it all new volume will be shown in the Listview, Same with the other buttons.

My questions is, do I need to copy all of my codes in Listview and put it under each button events? Or is there a way that I don't need to copy all my codes in my Listview and just call them and how since my SQL query is different from each status.

Here's my code below and also attached the screenshot:

[image: Excel VBA Userform]

```
Private Sub ListView_Data()
    
    
    Dim sql As String
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim Records As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim RecCount As Variant
    Dim fValue As Variant
    
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    
    con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=10.206.88.119\BIWFO;" & _
                          "Initial Catalog=TESTDB;" & _
                          "Uid=user; Pwd=pass1;"
                          
    sql = "select * from [TESTDB].[dbo].[tbl_MN_Omega_Raw]"
    
    rst.Open sql, con, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
    '~~> Get the records in an array
    Records = rst.GetRows
    '~~> Get the records count
    'RecCount = rst.RecordCount
    RecCount = CLng(rst.RecordCount)
    
    '~~> Populate the headers
    For i = 0 To rst.Fields.count - 1
        ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Add , , rst.Fields(i).Name, 200
    Next i
    
    rst.Close
    con.Close

    With ListView1
        .View = lvwReport
        .CheckBoxes = False
        .FullRowSelect = True
        .Gridlines = True
        .LabelWrap = True
        .LabelEdit = lvwManual
           
        Dim li As ListItem
        
        '~~> Populate the records
        For i = 0 To RecCount - 1
            Set li = .ListItems.Add(, , Records(0, i))
            For j = 1 To UBound(Records, 2)
            fValue = Records(j, i)
            If IsNull(fValue) Then fValue = ""    ' or maybe "(null)"
            li.ListSubItems.Add , , fValue

            Next j
        Next i
    End With
    
ERR_Handler:

    Select Case Err.Number
    
        Case 0
        Case Else
        
            MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, Err.Number
            
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: If the SQL-statement is the only difference you could set your "sql" varibale within the button and hand it over to the rest of you code

Comment: What do you mean by that? Sorry im newbie

Comment: I mean that you could set the variable that holds your SQL-statement ("sql") within the button you call the sub from and not the sub itself. This way you can assign different queries to different buttons without having to replicate the full code.

You would just need to add the ByRef to your Sub like this:

Private Sub ListView_Data(ByRef sql As String)